# Compare by NAME only, and not by NAME + EXTENSION using existing code; Python 3.x

Tags: python-3.x, filecompare

The python 3.x code (listed below) does a great job of comparing files from two different directories (Input_1 and Input_2) and finding the files that match (are the same between the two directories). Is there a way I can alter the existing code (below) to find files that are the same BY NAME ONLY between the two directories. (i.e. find matches by name only and not name + extension)?

```
comparison = filecmp.dircmp(Input_1, Input_2) #Specifying which directories to compare
common_files = ', '.join(comparison.common) #Finding the common files between the directories
TextFile.write("Common Files: " + common_files + '\n') # Writing the common files to a new text file
```

1. Example:

   - **Directory 1 contains**: Tacoma.xlsx, Prius.txt, Landcruiser.txt
   - **Directory 2 contains**: Tacoma.doc, Avalon.xlsx, Rav4.doc

"TACOMA" are two different files (different extensions). Could I use basename or splitext somehow to compare files by name only and have it return "TACOMA" as a matching file?

Comment: check my answer now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the file name, try:

```
from os import path
fil='..\file.doc'
fil_name = path.splitext(fil)[0].split('\\')[-1]
```

This stores `file` in `file_name`. So to compare files, run:

```
from os import listdir , path
from os.path import isfile, join
def compare(dir1,dir2):
    files1 = [f for f in listdir(dir1) if isfile(join(dir1, f))]
    files2 = [f for f in listdir(dir2) if isfile(join(dir2, f))]
    common_files = []
    for i in files1:
        for j in files2:
            if(path.splitext(i)[0] == path.splitext(j)[0]): #this compares it name by name.
                common_files.append(i)
    return common_files
```

Now just call it:

```
common_files = compare(dir1,dir2)
```

As you know python is case-sensitive, if you want common files, no matter if they contain uppers or lowers, then instead of:

```
if(path.splitext(i)[0] == path.splitext(j)[0]):
```

use:

```
if(path.splitext(i)[0].lower() == path.splitext(j)[0].lower()):
```

You're code worked very well! Thank you again, Infinity TM! The final use of the code is as follows for anyone else to look at. (Note: that Input_3 and Input_4 are the directories)

```
def Compare():
    Input_3 = #Your directory here
    Input_4 = #Your directory here
    files1 = [f for f in listdir(Input_3) if isfile(join(Input_3, f))]
    files2 = [f for f in listdir(Input_4) if isfile(join(Input_4, f))]
    common_files = []
    for i in files1:
        for j in files2:
            if(path.splitext(i)[0].lower() == path.splitext(j)[0].lower()):
                common_files.append(path.splitext(i)[0])
```

Comment: Thank you. I played around with your original comment for awhile and couldn't get it to work. I will give this a go in just awhile and let you know what I come up with.

Comment: Infinity TM, the code works very well! Thanks again! I made a slight tweak to the final line to leave out the file extension: common_files.append(path.splitext(i)[0])